# Getting meeting invites & events for the specific day for the logged in user using microsoft Graph API in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am working on a UWP app that's getting data from `Microsoft Graph API`. I need to get the list of all the meetings scheduled for the day for the logged in user.
I am authenticating the user from Azure AD and I am setting up few meetings/events according to my `timezone`.

I want to only fetch data for the current user based on his geography time and geography for the same day.

Example: Currently in India, If I set up a meeting at 7 PM IST, the same shall get converted to his current time zone and show.

I am using this API

```
string _graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location" (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location') ;
```

but I want to limit his meetings based on his login time -meetings that are passed, shouldn't be displayed.
Can anyone look into this
?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [calendar view](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) here. That way you can specify a start and end time and get back all events between the two.

Comment: how to make sure the time for the meeting get converted into the attendees's time zone ? I need to even get the list of all the attendees with their email ids , the organizer name , email id

Comment: Definitely try this out in the Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). You can add a header to the request to set time zone: `Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"`.

Comment: not working for me .I have added the header but its only showing data in UTC

Comment: Check response headers for a `Preference-Applied: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"`. If it's not there, you likely did not set the header correctly.

Comment: I used the above API and it returned me some data. In my meeting invite , I had attached few documents , is it possible to download those documents programatically ?